# Return new document id and use it again with one button

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a chat page in part of my application. There is a field in the document that recording members, user id and timestamp. Also in the same document, there is a sub-collection that recording messages.

There is FloatingActionButton that opens a form to write title and text. My problem starts after here.

**These codes are for onPress within the form.**

```
onPressed: () async {
                    if (_sohbetFormu.currentState.validate()) {
                      var docId;
                      var refOne = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("conversations");
                      await refOne.add({
                        "displayMessage": _textControllerTitle.text,
                        "members": _currentUid,
                      }).then((value) => docId = FieldPath.documentId);
                      _textControllerTitle.text = "";
                      var refTwo = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("conversations/$docId/messages");
                      await refTwo.add({
                        "senderId": _currentUid,
                        "message": _textControllerText.text,
                        "timeStamp": DateTime.now(),
                      });
                      _textControllerText.text = "";
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                  },
```

**First Problem:** I cant use same document Id for sub-collection and information field. I tried to use *FieldPath.documentId* but it didn't work. FieldPath.documentId didn't return any id.

**Second Problem** You see "members" in codes. It should be array and record members. But it's String at the moment. How can i change it to array?

Comment: Good to hear that you found a solution. For future questions: the Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: I fixed the tag of the post. Thanks for your warning.

Comment: I had already done that, and you changed that to be the wrong tag. I fixed it again, but you might want to take a look at the difference between the two databases (both can receiver realtime updates from the server, so that isn't it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problems.

**At first one:** I changed FieldPath.documentId to

```
.then((value) => docId = value.id);
```

**At second one:** I changed "message": _textControllerText.text, to

```
"members": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["$_currentUid"]),
```

I didn't delete the post just because it might work for others